# WriteableBitmap from Uri Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uri, writeablebitmap

Hi I'm having a problem with Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app.
I have to create a WriteableBitmap from an image i have on the phone.
I have my uri

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx;/Images/imageName.png");
```

but i honestly don't know how to use it to create a WriteableBitmap.
I found a lot of solutions but they all use

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImageName);
```

This code is not working on Windows Phone 8.1, the only constructor avaiable is

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(pixelHeight, pixelWidth);
```

bit i honestly don't know what to do.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks all

Comment: You can try this.

var uri = new Uri("ms-appx;/Images/imageName.png");
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(pixelHeight, pixelWidth);
using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    await wb.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}

Comment: @BlueRay i get Value does not fall within the expected range when using GetFileromApplicationUriAsync :(

Comment: Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/imageName.png");

Comment: Worked! thanks a lot, if you add the reply i vote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/imageName.png");
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pixelHeight, pixelWidth);
using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```